# How to remove alphabets from alphanumeric array c#

Tags: c#

I have an array with *alphanumerics*. How can I remove the *alphabets* to have a resulting array of just *numbers*?

For Example

```
 string[] strArray = new string[] {
   "A2", "B44", "C108", "A99", "DE8"};
```

will result in an array:

```
 string[] strArrayNum == {"2", "44", "108", "99", "8"}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself? If so, please edit your question with the code you have so far, and where you are getting stuck. As a good starting point, do you know how to do this operation for just *one* string, instead of an array?

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate it, replacing all of the non-digits with an empty space, eg:

```cs
var modified = strArray.Select(s => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "[^\\d]", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
   var strArrayNum = strArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

*Linq* solution:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] strArrayNum = strArray
  .Select(item => string.Concat(item.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')))
  .ToArray();
```

if you want `int[] strArrayNum`:

```
int[] strArrayNum = strArray
  .Select(item => item
     .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     .Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 10 + a - '0'))
  .ToArray();
```